# Insert document to collection using data from an "inner select" from another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 2 mongo collections: `admins` and `logs`

an 'admins' collection document looks like this:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("123456"),
   name: "John Doe",
   age: 33
}
```

I would like to insert, with one query, a new document to the 'logs' collection, that looks like this:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("778899"),
   action: "did something",
   adminUserId: "123456"   // just a plain string value, not ObjectId
}
```

So what I'm really asking is how I can insert a document, where a field value equals an "inner select statement" value,
i.e-

```
adminUserId = ([select one from collection 'admins' where name="John Doe"]._id.toString())
```

Any way to do it all in one mongo operation? I'm in node.js

Comment: it requires 2 queries, first find from admins and second add in logs.

Comment: Yes, already doing that. I'm curious whether this kind of action can be 'folded' into a single query, and also- if this kind of query will be more efficient than the simple approach of 1.fetch->2.insert

Comment: i don't think is there any folded query to do this, you really need to change schema design it is not good to query data from another collection and insert into another, or why don't you get _id instead of name, you can save one query.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation pipeline to retrieve the data you want inserted, then massage it if needed, then use $merge stage to insert it into an existing collection.